# Multiple Spots in one location with SAPUI5 Geomap

Tags: sapui5, geomap

I have a `GeoMap` control initiated and have something like 12,000 Spots displayed. I sometimes have multiple spots that are on the exact same coordinate, but have no differentiation to show me that I have more than one Spot in this location. I know this is achievable using a `Cluster` from `vbm`, but my scenario requires both options to work - **with** or **without** a `Cluster`.

My Map code looks like this:

```
var oVBI = new sap.ui.vbm.GeoMap('vbi', {
            width : "100%",
            height: "90%",
            resources : [
                new sap.ui.vbm.Resource({ 
                    "name" : getDataURL,
                    "src"  : getDataURL
                }) 
           ],
           vos : [ new sap.ui.vbm.Spots({
              customProperties: ["status"], 
              items : {
                path : "/spots",
                template: new sap.ui.vbm.Spot({ 
                    position: '{A1}',
                    tooltip: '{A2}',
                    click: that.onClickSpot,
                    contextMenu: that.onContextMenuSpot,
                    image: getDataURL,
                    type: "{type}",
                    customData: [
                        new sap.ui.core.CustomData({key:"status", value: '{status}'})
                    ]       
                })
              }
           }) ]
        });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.